# How to collect messages in one box? because the listener can return several for one post

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot

I use gramjs library to access Telegram API.
For example, i publish a new post in channel with 2 images and some description,
but instead of one message (with full info) I receive 2: description + photo and separately another photo.

```
client.addEventHandler((event) => {
   console.log('new post')
}, new NewMessage({chats: [someId]}))
```

I found out from the documentation that this is normal and to collect multiple messages into one they use parameters **pts** and **qts** (https://core.telegram.org/api/updates), in gramjs there is only **pts**, which is not very informative

I also found out that you can use a `new Album`, then similar messages will arrive at once in an array:

```
client.addEventHandler((event) => {
   console.log('new post')
}, new Album({chats: [someId]}))
```

But, this dont have any single messages with one photo or  just text.
We can use these listeners both, BUT then both listeners will receive these messages with albums, they need to be filtered out somehow in this case from NewMessage listener, otherwise messages will be processed twice from each listener.

How do handle this? Is there any solution with listener?

P.S. I think that the option is to take the identifier when receiving an event and, instead of reading the message, go through the ID to the channel using another method that will return the entire publication.

Described above, I don’t know how to work with updating content in the channel

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is an answer:

```
client.addEventHandler( async (event) => {
    const isSingleMessage = "message" in event && !event.message.groupedId;

    if (!isSingleMessage) {
      return;
    }

    console.log('message');
  }, new NewMessage({
    chats: [id],
  }));

client.addEventHandler( async (event) => {
    console.log('album');
  }, new Album({
    chats: [id],
  }))
```

The main difference is that messages that arrive in parts have groupId.